# How to redirect the JSON object in ASP.NET core with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ado.net

In my project I have displayed pop-ups in create, edit and delete. After I am clicking the create button enter the details and then submit, the page doesn't redirect to the index page. But data is updated. Why this errors. I was used jquery AJAX post submission. When I was clicking the events it does't redirect to the index view page.

In below my BookController Http Post action method What is the mistake in this code.

BookController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int id, [Bind("BookID,Title,Author,Price")] BookViewModel bookViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Sql Connection
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("BookConnection")))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("BookAddOrEdit", sqlConnection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BookID", bookViewModel.BookID);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", bookViewModel.Title);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Author", bookViewModel.Author);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", bookViewModel.Price);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        **return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        //return Json(new { isValid = true, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this,         "Index") });**
    }
    return Json(new {isValid= false,html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this,"AddOrEdit",   bookViewModel) });
}
```

Comment: Because you did ajax, so interpreting results is up to you not framework ... you post was prolly redirected and you end with this response but as ajax data so browser cannot display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ajax, you cannot use RedirectToAction to redirect to the index page.

You can change your return method like below:

```
return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Book") });
```

And add Success in Ajax like:

```
success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is very usefull to solve my program.